Problems with ngrok on Kali Linux
ERROR:  Error reading configuration file '/root/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml': YAML parsing error: yaml: unmarshal errors:
ERROR:    line 2: field authtoken not found in type config.v3yamlConfig
what i need to do, guys?
after editing .config and rename ngrok folder like on windows it`s get a 4018 error, after adding a token- ngrok give this problem

I get the same error. The quick fix was to downgrade ngrok from version 3.15.0 to 3.14.0 and change the config version from "3" to "2" in the ngrok.yml
I believe it might be related to the changes in a config file version, but I didn't have time to investigate further

I change the version from 2 to 3 en ~/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml and work for me.
